# How to collect a coroutine flow in java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm developing an Android library,

When the user receives a push notification it may contain deep links, that I need to return to the app.

I did in kotlin with no problem.

This is the function that is called when it needs to send the deep links

```
fun getDeepLinkFlow(): Flow<HashMap<String, String>?> = flow {
    emit(deepLinks)
}
```

And in my kotlin test app I managed to use with no problems as well, using like this.

```
GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext) {
    SDK.getDeepLinkFlow().collect { deepLinks ->
        println(deepLinks)
    }
}
```

But now, there's a RN project that whant to use the lib, in order to do that we are doing a RN module that joins the iOS code and the Android code. But it uses java.

So, how can I use the collect from Coroutines on a Java code? or what could I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines/`Flow` is inherently awkward to use from Java since it relies on transformed `suspend` code to work.

One possible solution is to expose an alternative way of consuming the `Flow` to your java code. Using the [RxJava integration library](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.flow.-flow/as-flowable.html) you can expose a compatible `Flowable` that the java side can consume.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to change the way deep links were used and start using the ViewModel with a liveData instead.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you're handling it on an activity or fragment a way to do this is using an extension function with a callback. Here's an example:

Kotlin extension:

```kotlin
fun MyActivity.observeScreenState(callbackToJava: (ScreenState) -> Unit) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.screenState.collect {
            callbackToJava(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Java code:

```java
observeScreenState(
    this,
    (ScreenState state) -> {
        doWhatever(state);
        return null;
    }
);
```